# Delegate Arguments - Base- / Derived Classes conflict

Tags: c#

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to C#, which is why i come to you all in hopes for some clarification. I have a EventDispatcher Class that defines a delegate:

```
delegate void EventHandler(BaseEvent evt);
```

and a few methods to use it:

```
void AddEventListener(string event_name, EventHandler handler)
void RemoveEventListener(string event_name, EventHandler handler = null)
void DispatchEvent(BaseEvent evt)
```

I also have derived Event Classes for Example `DerivedEvent` that inherits from `BaseEvent` and adds their own properties/fields on top.

As expected i would use it like so:

```
AddEventListener("my_event", MyEventHandler);
```

and my Handler Method would look something like this:

```
void MyEventHandler(BaseEvent evt)
```

Finally, the actual problem. Why can't i define a Handler that uses the derived event class as argument, like so:

```
void MyEventHandler(DerivedEvent evt)
```

I've tried even via Interfaces but that made no difference. I am currently casting within the method-body to the actual Event Class:

```
...
DerivedEvent actualEvent = (DerivedEvent)evt;
...
```

Is that really the only way? Hopefully somebody can enlighten me :)

Answer (score 0):

When the delegate is called the caller is allowed to pass in *any* `BaseEvent`.  It isn't necessarily a `DerivedEvent`.  Since the caller might be passing in an object that isn't a `DerivedEvent`, your handler can't assume that the value passed in is a `DerivedEvent`.

What you *can* do is add a handler that can accept not only any `BaseEvent`, but also other things.  For example, you could add a handler that accepts `object` as a parameter, because any `BaseEvent` that is passed in when the handler is invoke *will* be an `object`.

Comment: I don't quite follow. If i go further down the rabbit hole i will still be left with casting to the actual Class that the Event is from no?

Comment: @SandroDucceschi If the code calling the delegate is actually going to provide a `DerivedEvent` then *that* should be the parameter in the delegate.  If it's not, then there's nothing you can do, because the parameter isn't actually a `DerivedEvent`.  Casting is just making it fail at runtime instead of compile time.

Comment: well the idea is to have a system where i can pass any derived class from `BaseEvent`that will then call the appropriate handler that expects said derived class as argument. Like this:

    `AddEventListener(DerivedEvent.AN_EVENT, DerivedEventHandler);
    
void DerivedEventHandler(DerivedEvent evt);`


yet i was hoping by defining the BaseEvent as the argument of the delegate, that this would work for any such use. And yes, clearly it would fail if the argument would be of any other kind of Derived Event Class. Which is ok and expected.

Comment: @SandroDucceschi And I've explained to you why it doesn't, because the handler isn't necessarily always going to be given an object of any more specific type than `BaseEvent`; that's the most it can assume of its caller.

Comment: Gotcha! :) Sorry for being stubborn :). Is there an alternative way of achieving my goal? Or is this just a limitation i will have to live with?